# Why is useState value null inside function block?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I know there is a scoping issue here. I just can't find it. Why is 'items' null in the `searchItems()` block?

```
export const useStore = () => {
   const [items, setItems] = useState(null)

   const setItemsFromApi = () => {
      //call api to get data, then
      setItems(data)
   }

   const searchItems = (query) => {
      //use the local data and filter based on query
      //'items' IS NULL IN THIS SCOPE
      items.filter(() => {})
   }

   console.log(items) // 'items' HAS UPDATED VALUE AFTER setItemsFromApi() IN THIS SCOPE

   return {setItemsFromApi, searchItems}
}
```

Use store like this. (NOTE: I left out the rendering of the items in the list because that part works fine. Just focusing on why the onClick doesn't use the already loaded items to filter with.)

```
export default function DataList(props) => {     
   const store = useStore();

   useEffect(() => {
      store.setItemsFromApi()
   }, [])
    
   const runSearch = (query) => {
      store.searchItems(query)
   }

   return <button onClick={runSearch('searchTerm')}   
 }
```

I even tried passing it as a callback dependency, but it's still null

```
const searchItems = useCallback((query) => {
    //'items' IS STILL NULL IN THIS SCOPE
    items.filter(() => {})
 }, [items])
```

Comment: The state won't be immediately updated after you call store.setItemsFromApi(), it will only be updated after the next time the component rerenders. If you are calling store.searchItems immediately after then it will still be using the previous value of items

Comment: no, searchItems is not immediately called. 'items' get set when page loads. Then later I do a search

Comment: Please share the full code, the snippets you have posted aren't sufficient to help you solve your problem

Comment: code example is updated

Comment: The runSearch function is not passed correctly to the onClick prop of your button in your code example. It should be `<button onClick={() => runSearch('searchTerm')} />` otherwise runSearch will be instantly executed as soon as that component renders

Answer (score 0):

From the code you posted,

> const store = useStore()
> store.setItemsFromApi()
> ...
> store.searchItems(query)

the issue may be because you are doing an async operation (calling the API), but the search is not waiting for the result of the fetch call. So, when you do the

> store.searchItems(query)

, the store is null and only changes its value later.

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, the state wasn't refreshing after triggering a search because I had a "debounce" `useRef` function running within the component when the onChange event was fired, even though this was a local data search. I guess this interrupted the re-render event. So I removed it.